# Uploaded images: uploaded SVGs do not fit display container

Tags: javascript, css, angular, frontend

I have a form with an upload image field. Images can be png, jpeg or svgs.
When the image is uploaded and is an SVG, is doesnt fit the container size.

Cloudify is being used to handle the URL of the uploaded data. The component will just handle to display the URL transformed by cloudify...I need the sgvs to fit on this container when being displayed.

Is not a SVG inline, I have no control of the format the user will upload.

```
<img
  class="vehicle-image"
  [src]="provUrl(imageUrl)"
  alt="Uploaded Image"
/>

.vehicle-image {
  object-fit: contain;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

it works fine for pngs or jpegs, but not for SVGs...what could I have to work this around for SVGs also?

Comment: Hi provide the url of the svg file. currently its difficult to assist because of lack of data

Comment: Cloudify is being used to handle the URL of the uploaded data. There is not control of which SVG will be uploaded. The component will just handle to display the URL transformed by cloudify...I need the sgvs to fit on this container when being displayed

Comment: @Anna add your container code also and make [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What is the parent of ```.vehicle-image```? ```width: 100%; height: 100%;``` will not limit an image from pushing beyond boundaries if parent has no relative position for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SVGs you need to provide a height and width values. If you provide height and width of 100% to the SVG, it will occupy the full width and height of its bouding box. PNG and JPEG has fixed height and width so it will not stretch beyond those dimensions.

One solution is to wrap the `img` tag in a `div` tag and provide a max-height and max-width to that div element.

```
 <div class="img-div">
    <img
  class="vehicle-image"
  src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/NewTux.svg"
  alt="Uploaded Image"
/>        
</div>
```

CSS

```
.vehicle-image {
    object-fit: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }
 .img-div {
   max-width: 200px;
   max-height: 200px;
}
```

Working link: [Replit](https://replit.com/@santhoshss471/AngularSO)

Comment: Thank you, Santhosh! I manage to make it work wrapping them up.